# postgresql csv copy unquoted newline found in data

Tags: postgresql, csv, postgresql-copy

I have some csv data in excel, and I'm importing it into postgresql.  I'm opening the excel csv file with a notepad editor (have tried notepad, wordpad and notepad++) and am then copying/pasting into a remote desktop connection to a linux machine.  Then I'm using this import statement from within the database:
COPY ltg_data FROM '/home/keene/ltg_db/ltg_outbreak_jun9_15.csv' (FORMAT CSV, HEADER);

I get this error: 
ERROR:  unquoted newline found in data
HINT:  Use quoted CSV field to represent newline.
CONTEXT:  COPY ltg_data, line 175320

Here's the link to the csv file I'm using: http://greenandtheblue.com/ltg_outbreak_jun9_15.csv
I've researched the issue a lot and tried a lot of things and must be missing something fairly simple.  Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Don't copy/paste into a "remote desktop? (ssh?) connection to the remote machine. Copy the CSV file instead. The problem is that your terminal emulator is probably introducing line breaks.

Comment: I have to get some permissions changed to do that, but I'll give it a try.

Comment: Solved!  I just copied the actual file to the remote machine and ran the copy statement, and it worked fine.  Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 10):

The file you linked doesn't appear to have CR-LF line endings, however I suspect that could potentially be an issue since you're coming from a Windows host. You might try removing carriage returns using `sed`:

`sed 's/\r//' ltg_outbreak_jun9_15.csv ltg_outbreak_jun9_15-noCR.csv`

Then COPY FROM the resulting ...-noCR.csv file.

Comment: or even easier sed -i 's/\r//g' ltg_outbreak_jun9_15.csv

Comment: use `--quite` option

Comment: in my csv the last column was empty but without quotas and CR was used as line end i.e. `,\r`. I opened the file in IntelliJ and switched EOL to CRLF and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the carriage returns using `sed` as thinkmassive said, but to save the results into a new file on Linux you need:

`touch ltg_outbreak_jun9_15-noCR.csv`

`sed 's/\r//' ltg_outbreak_jun9_15.csv > ltg_outbreak_jun9_15-noCR.csv`

Answer (score -1):

The answer is very simple.

- Add a page break in your excel file where your data ends.
- Select just next cell (empty cell) after your last data cell and go to

  `File > Page Layout > Breaks > Insert Page Break`.
- Save your `csv file` and `import` it again with `pgadmin`.

Comment: The issue was resolved by not trying to copy and paste via a terminal emulator (as seen above in the comments)